# CMDER not finding sudo and pip commands

Tags: python, linux, bash, pip, virtualenv

So I have been using regular windows command prompt and wanted to try using bash as most forums give commands in bash and it's a little cumbersome to try to find the translation to windows. Currently trying out Spotify API and I want to run a virtual environment.

I do the following windows command and everything runs fine:

[WINDOWS]

python -m pip install virtualenv

this, does not:

[BASH]

pip install virtualenv

and I get returned bash: pip: command not found

SO I go to install pip using sudo easy_install pip and get returned bash: sudo: command not found.

I am running CMDER as admin in bash so I thought ok, I will try easy_install pip and returned bash: easy_install: command not found. SO i went to the actual python directory and went to install pip again and no luck.

Any insight on how I can address this?

[Windows]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrpim.png)[Bash][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEVty.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install pip by downloading the get-pip.py from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and then run it using `python get-pip.py`

After that

You might need to set your Environment Variable to include PIP in your path. you can use Environment Variables in Control Panel and add the path to System Variables.

[image]

Comment: Im using CMDER which is a bash emulator on my windows machine. I am already running as admin in which I already tried easy_install pip (after trying sudo) and still no luck :-/

Comment: have you tried installing pip using get-pip.py instead of easy_install?

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it returns bash: get-pip.py: command not found. I think that there might be a console incompatibility? I have pip, virtualenv and python installed already on my machine, but the bash console is not being able to recognize it.

Comment: can you use pip command in windows cmd? (without "python -m" part). Maybe you need to configure your environment variables. The easiest way will be to use control panel or you can use `setx` command

Comment: Oh let me try that. I always have to use python -m whenever I am installing anything python related. I thought that was just the norm. Let me try this and get back to you!

Comment: If you installed as a non-admin and use an admin account it will fail; ti won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Not sure what causes it, but switching to cmd.exe and running pip install ... worked without issue.